# Go on Top in UITableView with a Searchbar

Tags: ios

if I want that the TableView goes on Top, I have used a Button with this Code:

```
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

But its not really cool to use a Button to do this Action.

Is there a better way to do this? Should the User tapping 2x and then goes to the Top?

What is the best way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated
It's probably a better idea than scrolling with scrollRectToVisible.

Comment: Ok, but the Question is, what is the best way to activate this Action for the User. The Funktion - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {} doesn't work. How is it possible, that this Action will be activated, if the User (for example) tapping twice at the TableView.

Comment: Nobody? To do this with a Button is really disgusting.

Comment: How about adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the table view? You could then change the value for "numberOfTapsRequired", which is 1 by default to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Replies, i have solved the Problem within the Rows. If a User tapping longer on a Row, he will be pushed to Top.

Call that in your Function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//Action -> long pressing on a Cell
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture =
        [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)] autorelease];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
}
```

Add this Function to your Class

```
//Method
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    // only when gesture was recognized, not when ended
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // get affected cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];

        // get indexPath of cell
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        // do something with this action
        NSLog(@"Long-pressed cell at row %@", indexPath);

        //go to the first Row
        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I hope that helps anyone.